# Is it a game mechanics or game mechanics?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> People tend to dislike a game mechanics that's complex.
>
> People tend to dislike game mechanics that are complex.

I know some people use "a game" even though mechanics is always in plural, but how do you refer to one game mechanics in particular instead of the whole thing? It's confusing, because usage is all over the place on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noun is "mechanic" (singular) or "mechanics" (plural). In each case the noun is modified by the noun-cum-adjective "game" which, being an adjective, is never pluralized.

So you can refer to multiple "game mechanics" or a singular "game mechanic." Saying "a game mechanics" would be incorrect. (Though you could make the subject *game* and talk about *a game'**s*** mechanic(s)."